# Coding to print PDF files from file paths in query results

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm not new to Access, but am very new to VBA coding. Our management software is horrible, but it's the best that is available in the industry and I have created many many reports using Access, but have new problem now.

Attachments in the system are stored in one central location and then the file name stored in a SQL table. I have created queries to pull the full file path including the file name. Would it be possible to use some VBA coding to print all the existing PDFs in sequence from the paths returned in the query?

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Please share the code you tried and the exact issue you encountered.  That will allow us to help you better.

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-vba-to-open-print-a-pdf-file ("VBA print PDF")

Comment: @jdv, Interesting article but incomplete. FileLocked function is not explained nor code provided. RetVal variable is not declared. There is an error referencing variable `sStrPDFFileName` - extra 's'.

Comment: My greater point is that this is not an unknown request, and my search terms got a lot of hits. Yes, one might have to use a third-party library of some sort.

Comment: Here is code that actually works. However, it does leave Acrobat open after print. https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/147038-print-a-pdf-file-using-vba

Comment: I have no code. When I said very new to VBA I meant it. In all my time with Access, I've created and generated lots of reports, but never had to do anything deeper than macros.

Answer (score -1):

Native VBA controls the collections of methods and attributes from Office.
An existent PDF is not the case (Access can create one or open, but not open and print).

To open a file with full path you will need to perform a select from table and perform a loop to shell open file, after that, sendkeys ^P.

But I strongly recomend to use another tool to do it, like Auto Hotkey or AutoIt.

Comment: That's plain untrue... VBA can do this just fine, either through automating explorer and using the print verb, automating Internet Explorer, automating Adobe Acrobat, take your pick. Acrobat, Internet Explorer and file explorer all have type libraries and can work natively with VBA.